# How to split a string based of capital letters?

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I have a string I need to split based on capital letters,my code below

```js
let s = 'OzievRQ7O37SB5qG3eLB';
var res = s.split(/(?=[A-Z])/)
console.log(res);
```

But there is a twist,if the capital letters are contiguous I need the regex to "eat" until this sequence ends.In the example above it returns

..R,Q7,O37,S,B5q,G3e,L,B

And the result should be

RQ7,O37,SB5q,G3e,LB

Thoughts?Thanks.

Comment: 'OzievRQ7O37SB5qG3eLB'.match(/[A-Z]+[^A-Z]+/g) ?

Comment: @Andrey Post it as an answer

Comment: Wiktor got it :) His regex is actually better

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to match these chunks with `/[A-Z]+[^A-Z]*|[^A-Z]+/g` instead of splitting with a zero-width assertion pattern, because the latter (in your case, it is a positive lookahead only regex) will have to check each position inside the string and it is impossible to tell the regex to skip a position once the lookaround pattern is found.

```js
s = 'and some text hereOzievRQ7O37SB5qG3eLB';
console.log(s.match(/[A-Z]+[^A-Z]*|[^A-Z]+/g));
```

See the [**online regex demo at regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/w1ECPP/2).

**Details**:

- `[A-Z]+` - one or more uppercase ASCII letters
- `[^A-Z]*` - *zero or more* (to allow matching uppercase only chunks) chars other than uppercase ASCII letters
- `|` - or
- `[^A-Z]+` - one or more chars other than uppercase ASCII letters (to allow matching non-uppercase ASCII letters at the start of the string.

The `g` global modifier will let `String#match()` return all found non-overlapping matches.

Comment: If the input may potentially start with a non-capital letter, you may add `[^A-Z]+` as an alternative to the regex: `'aBc'.match(/[A-Z]+[^A-Z]*|[^A-Z]+/g)` returns `["a", "Bc"]`